# nginx fails to start and throws error for sudo nginx -t

Tags: nginx

nginx. Using Ubuntu on windows 10 home.

I see the below error when trying sudo nginx -t

[sudo nginx -t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA3gn.png)

nginx fails to start

[sudo service nginx start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/600k7.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to start nginx on a privileged port. You cannot open a privileged port (<=1024) as non-root user. Hence the permission denied error. Try with `:8080` or any other non-privileged ports maybe?

Comment: Thank You [Vivek Sasidharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4050406/vivek-sasidharan), its working fine now

Comment: @GouthamKumarG Good to hear that. Please mark the answer in that case!